# How to choose in postgresql rows where amount of one value is bigger than another?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-functions, having-clause

how to choose in postgresql rows where amount of one value is bigger than another?
For example I need to choose only those where recommended is bigger:

[image]

In other words:

```
create table t(id bigint, place text, opinion text);
insert into t values
    (1, 'mnt', 'yes'),
    (2, 'mnt', 'no'),
    (3, 'mnt', 'no'),
    (4, 'cod', 'yes'),
    (5, 'cod', 'yes'),
    (6, 'cod', 'yes'),
    (7, 'qrw', 'yes'),
    (8, 'qrw', 'no'),
    (9, 'caf', 'no'),
    (10, 'mnt', 'yes');
```

I tried to count group by place, opinion

Comment: What results do you want?  What counts are you talking about?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to get those rows where recommended will be bigger than 'not recommended'

Comment: What is "bigger"? Are you saying you want "recommended" or "not recommended" or a higher id? something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for places where recommended is bigger than not recommended, you can use aggregation:

```
select place
from t
group by place
having count(*) filter (where opinion = 'recommended') > count(*) filter (where opinion = 'not recommended');
```

You can also express this a bit more simply as:

```
select place
from t
where opinion in ('recommended', 'not recommended')
group by place
having avg( (opinion = 'recommended)::int ) > 0.5;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want places with more "recommended" opinions than "not recommended". If so, you can use aggregation and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select place
from mytable
group by place
having count(*) filter(where opinion = 'recommended') 
     > count(*) filter(where opinion = 'not recommended')
```

If you want the details of such rows, you can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        count(*) filter(where opinion = 'recommended'    ) over(partition by place) as cnt_recommended,
        count(*) filter(where opinion = 'not recommended') over(partition by place) as cnt_not_recommended
    from mytable t
) t
where cnt_recommended > cnt_not_recommended
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I need

Comment: @ДенисИванов: welcome. I should highlight that Gordon Linoff had pretty much the same answer as mine, and posted it a few seconds earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Another GROUP BY/HAVING alternative.

```
select place
from tablename
group by place
having sum(case when opinion = 'recommended' then 1
                when opinion = 'not recommended' then -1
           end) > 0
```

**Edit:** @Abelisto suggested this, to sort from recommended to less recommended:

```
select place
from tablename
group by place
order by sum(case when opinion = 'recommended' then 1
                  when opinion = 'not recommended' then -1
             end) desc
```

**Edit 2**

```
select
    place,
    sum(
        case
            when opinion = 'recommended' then 1
            when opinion = 'not recommended' then -1
            else 0
        end) as rate
from tablename
group by place
order by rate desc
```

Comment: +1 BTW `order by desc` instead of `having` could be more interesting for specialists. Like "The most efficient... still efficient but not so good... average... mostly unusable..."

Comment: @Abelisto, good idea, edited.